# Asynchronous SqlConnection - return something other than a Task

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asynchronous, data-access-layer

I have a data access layer in a WinForms app, which queries a SQL Server database. It contains several DAO. In one particular case, the following method throws an exception: "BeginExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting."

```
public List<Product> readAllProducts()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    string queryGetAllProducts = "SELECT * FROM Products;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryGetAllProducts, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.OpenAsync();

            Task<SqlDataReader> readerTask = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            SqlDataReader reader = readerTask.Result;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 // read the data...
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
           throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above, I have tried wrapping the execution of the query in a `lock` statement, to no avail. The idea is to have a responsive UI while database operations are being done, something which has already been achieved for other methods in this class which have `void` return types, with the `async`-`await` pattern. How can concurrency be achieved when needing to return an object (or collection of objects, as is the case above)?

Comment: See that call to `conn.OpenAsync();`? That's an asynchronous operation. You must await it. In general if you call a method that ends in -Async and returns a Task or Task<T>, it must be awaited. Also, you should ditch that useless try/catch, which allow you to use a using statement to dispose of the connection instead of doing it manually.

Comment: async/await was added to the language precisely because using it is *much* easier than the forms of asynchrony that existed previously.  You're *way* better off converting your asynchronous methods to return tasks, and then awaiting the async methods you need to call, than trying to use one of the older forms of asynchrony that doesn't use tasks.

Comment: @mason then the method must be `async`, in which case it would have to return a `Task<List<Product>>`. The caller of this method could then extract the list by getting the `Result` of the task, but it would have to `await` that as well (wouldn't it?), and so on up the chain. Is this the way to go or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Al2110 If you call `Result` on the task your program will deadlock, in addition to making the program no longer be asynchronous.  You need to await it, so that your program stays asynchronous.  And yes, you'll need to make the entire call chain asynchronous for the program to behave asynchronously.

Comment: @Al2110 - that's how introducing `async`/`await` to a code base tends to go. You keep moving further and further up the call stack converting each caller to `async` until it's all the way through.

Comment: @mason regarding your suggestion with the `try`-`catch` block. Could you elaborate on this a little more? In this case, I want to catch that exception and throw it up the stack until it reaches the "top" level of the program, which is actually a button click event handler in a form.

Comment: But why would you bother catching it if the *only* thing you're going to do is just throw it? Might as well just let it bubble up on its own - that try/catch is buying you absolutely nothing. It's just making your code longer.

Comment: @mason that makes sense. I was caught up in the idea of catching and dealing with an exception as soon as it happens.

Comment: You weren't *dealing* with it though. Try/catch is often abused. Catch an exception if you want to wrap it in a new exception that contains additional detail, or to log certain data that's only available in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it would have to await that as well (wouldn't it?), and so on up the chain

Yes, exactly that; `await` is contagious. So, you'd end up with:

```cs
public async Task<List<Product>> ReadAllProducts()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    string queryGetAllProducts = "SELECT * FROM Products;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but noting that a *lot* more of the operations here are `async`-compatible - `ReadAsync` etc for example. Or to make it simple, just get Dapper to do the heavy lifting:

```cs
public async Task<List<Product>> ReadAllProducts()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        var products = await conn.QueryAsync<Product>("SELECT * FROM Products;");
        return products.AsList();
    }
}
```

Your calling usage would then `await` this:

```cs
var data = await ReadAllProducts();
// do something with "data"
```

Comment: I have a `static` "service" class whose job it is to pass "pure" objects (`Product` for instance) to the UI. In fact, it calls the data access layer methods. It looks as though I was stuck by the fact that eventually, there would have to be a `void` method which extracts the object from the `Task`. The `var data = await ReadAllProducts()` line could go in there. A solution to this problem would be to avoid having this class `static`, and have a member which stores the objects, which can be set by such a method. I wanted to avoid having to do this change, but it appears that is the way to go.

Comment: @Al2110 Static/async don't have to be used or not used together. That said: static classes are often (but not always) a sign that something hasn't been designed right. Static classes are harder to handle when unit testing because it tightly couples your logic to an implementation rather than an abstraction. And it makes it harder to swap implementations of a dependency later on. I suggest you watch [Deep Dive into Dependency Injection and Writing Decoupled Quality Code and Testable Software](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412).